# Eclipse Save Actions vs Code Clean Up

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to get Eclipse to use the configuration settings from Java->Code Style->Clean Up automatically when I turn on "Perform the selection actions on save" in Java->Editor->Save Actions? It seems redundant to have to do all that configuration in two places.

Comment: Good question. Did you find an answer?

Comment: No. We just have to duplicate everything.

Comment: `Clean Up` is intended for large, project-wide and time-consuming formatting that should be performed after the project has been substantially changed, and not every time a file is saved. On the contrary, `Save Actions` are intended for relatively small and time-sensitive formatting that should take place every time the project is slightly changed. These changes shouldn't take a long time to complete nor change the file too much so as to not disrupt the coding process.

Answer (score 2):

This seams to be an open issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=178429

What could possibly work as workaround is to export the clean up actions as xml and then extract the properties from there (by replacing `<setting id="` with empty string,  `value="` by `=`, `"/>` by empty string and `cleanup` by `sp_cleanup`):

```
<setting id="cleanup.use_autoboxing" value="false"/>
<setting id="cleanup.always_use_this_for_non_static_method_access" value="false"/>
<setting id="cleanup.qualify_static_method_accesses_with_declaring_class" value="false"/>
<setting id="cleanup.organize_imports" value="false"/>
<setting id="cleanup.remove_trailing_whitespaces_ignore_empty" value="false"/>
<setting id="cleanup.lazy_logical_operator" value="false"/>
```

The result will look something like the following

```
sp_cleanup.use_autoboxing=false
sp_cleanup.always_use_this_for_non_static_method_access=false
sp_cleanup.qualify_static_method_accesses_with_declaring_class=false
sp_cleanup.organize_imports=false
sp_cleanup.remove_trailing_whitespaces_ignore_empty=false
sp_cleanup.lazy_logical_operator=false
```

In your workspace you then can open the file **.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs** and replace all **sp_cleanup** entries with the extracted ones. I think this will work with the most properties. Make a backup of the configuration file before changing it.